# How to keep the structure of the Tablix when there is no data to show

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, ssrs

We have a SSRS report which shows the result of a dataset in a tablix. If the query in the dataset returns no data, the header of the Tablix gets displayed but not the tablix cells below the header. I know there is a property to `NoRowMessage`, but in fact it is not what we want. Because when I specify a message, SSRS shows the message instead of the empty tablix.I must show the tablix structure as it is, but with empty cells.

I even set the rule for each cell value of the tablix using `IsNothing` function, to show blank (""), if the value is null, but it didn't help.

Do you have any idea? 
Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Might take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3442296/847990

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can add a row outside of the outermost group right under the tablix header row.
[image]

Set the row visibility to Show or hide based on an expression.  The expression would like like:

```
=iif(CountRows("DataSet1") > 0, true, false)
```

When there is no data, the table will show the headers and empty row.

[image]

When there is data, the empty row will be hidden.

Comment: Great Solution! Just FYI - `CountRows("DataSet") > 0` will resolve to `True` or `False` by itself, so you don't need to wrap in the `iif` statement, just let it resolve.  Also, if you've filtered the Tablix in any way, this will count the number of rows in the original dataset.  To get the [count of rows in a filtered tablix](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10946820/1366033) use `=COUNT("Fields.[pick any field].Value")` or [drop the "datatable1](https://clinthuijbers.wordpress.com/2014/12/04/ssrs-hide-a-tablix-is-case-no-rows-are-displayed-row-count-after-applying-a-filter/) and use `CountRows()`