# Report-builder: How can I show the labels in a List when the dataset is empty?

Tags: ssrs, report-builder

An equivalent question was answered for a **tablix**, but I would like to do this for a **list**:
"how to keep the structure of a tablix where there is no data".

I am showing about half a dozen fields in the list, each with their own label (which I want to repeat for each row).
If there are no rows, the user would like to use the report as a "template" that can be filled in manually so I would like to print the labels at least once.

[How to keep the structure of the Tablix when there is no data to show](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/48101/how-to-keep-the-structure-of-the-tablix-when-there-is-no-data-to-show)

Answer (score 0):

Occurs to me that I can do this by adding an empty record if the select returns no row; is that the best option?